# Android Bluetooth Socket not giving expected acknowledgement

Tags: android, bluetooth, outputstream, bluetooth-socket, bluetooth-profile

I'm sending a byte array to a bluetooth socket and I get a response from the bluetooth printer, but I'm not getting a correct sending acknowledgement for image data.

I write the byte array to `outputstream` the following way:

```
byte[] queryData = new byte[]{
    0x1B, 0x2A, 0x43, 0x41,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x27, 0x5E,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
outputStream.write(queryData);
outputStream.flush();
```

Is there any other way to write binary data to `outputstream`?

I'm stuck and opened to any suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399382/make-a-bytes-packet-and-send-to-external-accessory-device-for-print-using-blueto

Comment: A2A  iT WILL HELP YOU :  http://androidnutts.blogspot.in/2013/09/print-receipt-using-bluetooth-with.html

Comment: @Sanket Prabhu In my problem i have to send image size before sending image, after send this the printer have to give me proper ACK to send image. then i can send image data. i can use your solution after that ACK receive, i already done with code after ACK receive.

Comment: After sending the data, why don't you check with InputStream?

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450406/how-to-receive-serial-data-using-android-bluetooth may be this will be helpful

Comment: @BhaveshDesai Make sure your are sending bytes as per guidelines of printer manufacturer

Comment: Yes i am sending same way as in  manufacturer's documentation given.